# Bootstrap navbar collapsed button doesn't disappear when display gets larger

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm new to web development in general and I have this issue with Bootstrap:

[the navbar on a large display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShZKn.png)

the button should be visible only on smaller screens (on the right and than collapse), but when the display gets larger - the button sticks to my navbar-logo instead of disappearing :\

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"
                ><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo"
            /></a>
            <!-- dropdown btn -->
            <button
                class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                type="button"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarResponsive"
            >
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- nav-links -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">about</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">team</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">connect</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `<button class="navbar-toggle collapsed"` to `<button class="navbar-toggler"`

With your code it states that the navbar is always in "collapsed" state, so it doesnt work. If my anwser helped pls upvote it and check is as answered!

Answer (score 0):

The only issue here is with your button. I would make a slightly bigger change than the one suggested by Hakfo:

```
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
```

This will mean that the button only appears on smaller screens and will disappear everywhere else.